# Testing: FakeApplication ignoring additionalConfiguration

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, specs2

I'm trying to add a test on a Play 2.0 w/Scala project:

```
"Application" should {

    "return 404 on the index Action if web is disabled " in {
      running(FakeApplication(additionalConfiguration = Map(("enable.webInterface" -> "false")) )) {

        Config.IS_WEB_ENABLED must beFalse

        val result = controllers.Application.index()(FakeRequest())

        status(result) must equalTo(NOT_FOUND)
        contentType(result) must beSome("text/html")
        charset(result) must beSome("utf-8")
      }
    }
}
```

The value `Config.IS_WEB_ENABLED`is defined as:

```
object Config {

  lazy val IS_WEB_ENABLED = Play.configuration.getBoolean("enable.webInterface").getOrElse(false)

}
```

As you can see the test I try to override the configuration setting for `enable.webInterface` to false as the `application.conf` file has it set to true by default. But FakeApplication is not getting the new configuration value.

Any idea about what I'm missing there?

Comment: Using it in your application works? It only ignores it in test context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `def` instead of `lazy val`, maybe you used Config.IS_WEB_ENABLED before and it was initialized with true and returns only the same result because it's a val.

```
object Config {

  def IS_WEB_ENABLED = Play.configuration.getBoolean("enable.webInterface").getOrElse(false)

}
```

Comment: When I first tried I was missing the "current" reference mentioned by Nico_ekito. Once I have current, this solves it. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that `Play.configuration` does not take the fake application into account.

So try with this (using `current`):

```
object Config {

  lazy val IS_WEB_ENABLED = Play.current.configuration.getBoolean("enable.webInterface").getOrElse(false)

}
```

Comment: unfortunately no, it doesn't solve the issue :( Nice one though, I was convinced it was this!

Comment: arf, I was confident too ;-) Any way to print out the content of the config ?

Comment: in the end it was a combination of your answer and @Schleichardt answer, it seems. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

THe `Map` passed in `FakeApplication` is a `Map[String, String]` and you are requesting a boolean from the configuration. I would suspect the value not being picked up because it does not have the right type. What happens if you try

```
Play.configuration.getString("enable.webInterface")
```

instead ?