# Pool has been Shutdown (HikariDataSource) when testing

Tags: scala, playframework, specs2, playframework-2.4, hikaricp

After migrating an application to Play 2.4 and introducing dependency injection into the controller of the application, I'm getting "Pool has been Shutdown" when running unit tests. The affected tests are something like this:

```
@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])

class ApplicationSpec extends Specification {
  "Application" should {
    "doSomething" in running(TestUtil.app) {
      val myId = IdGen.newId("someone")
      ...
    }
  }

}
```

Where the IdGen class looks something like:

```
object IdGen {

  def newId(name: String): ClientCredentials = {
    DB.withTransaction("myDb") { implicit conn =>
      ...
    }
  }

}
```

The test fails on the DB.withTransaction() call with

```
[error]    Pool has been shutdown (HikariDataSource.java:89)
[error] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:89)
[error] play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.getConnection(Databases.scala:143)
[error] play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.withConnection(Databases.scala:153)
[error] play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.withTransaction(Databases.scala:162)
[error] play.api.db.DB$.withTransaction(DB.scala:72)
[error] com.example.idGen$.newId...
```

I'm initializing TestUtil.app with

```
object TestUtil {

  lazy val app = new GuiceApplicationBuilder()
      .configure(defaultConfig ++ Helpers.inMemoryDatabase("myDB"))
      .bindings(new TestModule) // Mock injections for test
      .build

}
```

Clearly I'm missing something to get the database up and running for tests, but I'm unsure what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this.

Tried to replace lazy val with def, as answered in this question: [Testing: FakeApplication ignoring additionalConfiguration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13333718/testing-fakeapplication-ignoring-additionalconfiguration?rq=1)

Which solved the problem.

Would love if someone could explain why?

Comment: You want a new app for each spec, which is what you get with a `def`. With a lazy val the same app instance persists across tests, leading to attempts to use it after its lifecycle has completed and its components (e.g. Hikari) shut down.

Answer (score 0):

This problem bit me because I was holding on to Application state in the code. Since tests typically each get their own `FakeApplication`, squireled-away state from one `FakeApplication` instance, when used in the context of another `FakeApplication` instance, will lead to problems. A concrete example is `play.api.Play.current` - this needs to be re-evaluated for each `FakeApplication` instance and shouldn't be held (after being evaluated only once) in your code.